# Invoking function getting stuck in a recursive loop and never comes

Tags: objective-c, recursion

I am learning Objective-C inheritance and my program is getting lost in a recursive loop and won't come out. It gets hung up when calling a getter function.

I am using XCode version: Version 6.2 (6C101)

[image: XCode Recursive loop]

My program is given below

Vehicle.h

```
#ifndef exercise_2_Vehicle_h
#define exercise_2_Vehicle_h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Vehicle : NSObject

@property float speed;


  -(void) start;

  -(void) stop;

  -(void) park;

 @end

#endif
```

Vehicle.m

```
#import "Vehicle.h"

@implementation Vehicle

-(void) setSpeed:(float)speed {
    self.speed = speed;
}

-(float) speed {
    return self.speed;
}

-(void) start {
    NSLog(@"Starting the vehicle");
}

-(void) stop {
    NSLog(@"Stopping the vehicle");
}

-(void) park {
    NSLog(@"Parking the vehicle");
}


@end
```

Car.h

```
#ifndef exercise_2_Car_h
#define exercise_2_Car_h

#import "Vehicle.h"
@interface Car : Vehicle
@property (nonatomic) NSString* make;


-(Car*) initMake: (NSString*) make;

-(NSString*) make;


@end
#endif
```

Car.m

```
#import "Car.h"

@implementation Car


-(Car*) initMake:(NSString *)make {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.make = make;
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString*) make {
    return self.make;
}
@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "Car.h"
#import "Vehicle.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        Car* car = [[[Car alloc] init] initMake: @"Camry"];
        //[car setSpeed:45];
        NSLog(@"The model initialized is ");
        [car make];
       // [car speed];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Car* car = [[[Car alloc] init] initMake: @"Camry"]; change this to  Car* car = [[Car alloc]  initMake: @"Camry"]; try this

Comment: @Spynet Thank you. I was wondering what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is caused by creating the property for speed:

```
@property float speed;
```

and overriding `setSpeed:` method.

When you create @property compiler adds two methods for you, in your example setSpeed and speed.
This command:

```
self.speed = speed;
```

is equal to:

```
[self setSpeed: speed];
```

and inside setSpeed you have this command again which cause the loop. In your example you can remove both methods (setSpeed and speed) because compiler will add it for you. If you need it because you want to do some customisation you should use _speed instead self.speed.
_speed is backed variable added by compiler when using @property.
Change your method to:

```
-(void) setSpeed:(float)speed {
    _speed = speed;
}
```

to remove the infinite loop.

Comment: How does "_" work in objective-c? I have just started reading apple docs and I can't make head or tail of it.

Answer (score 1):

In the

```
- (NSString*)make;
```

use

```
return _make
```

instead. The same with the speed.

If you return "self.x" in a getter method, then it's going to try and call the method again because you're requesting it on self. XCode will automatically convert the properties into variables that can be accessed with an '_' character, so you don't need to do any extra work.

You could also ignore our advice and remove both the "speed" and "make" getter methods you have made, because XCode automagically creates them for you.

Comment: Hi, Joey, I have a question. How does "_" denote in Objective-C land? What does "_make" denote?

Comment: When you use @property, you don't really create anything. The compiler will read this and convert them to "instance variables". It will also create "getters" and "setters" for the instance variables. When you do "self.myVariable", you're actually calling the generated getter. If you wish to override the getter or setter, then you must use the generate instance variable if you wish to change anything. Outside of the setters and getters, you can change the instance variable using "self.myVar = 10" or something, because this just calls the setter. The _ is a way of accessing the instance variable